# Python: Save Excel File As-Is To Folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm downloading Excel files from a website using beautifulsoup4.

I only need to download the files. I don't need to rename them, just download them to a folder, relative to where the code is.

the function takes in a beautifulsoup call, searches for `<a>` then makes a call to the links.

```
def save_excel_files(sfile):
    print("starting")
    for link in sfile.find_all("a"):
        candidate_link = link.get("href")
        if (candidate_link is not None
            and "Flat.File" in candidate_link):
            xfile = requests.get(candidate_link)
            if xfile:
                ### I just don't know what to do...
```

I've tried using `os.path` ; `with open("xtest", "wb") as f:` and many other variations. Been at this for two evenings and totally stuck.

The first issue is that I can't even get the files to downlaod and save anywhere. `xfile` resolves to `[response 200]`, so that part is working, I'm just having a hard time coding the actual download and save.

Comment: What is the error you get with `with open('test.xls', 'wb') as f: f.write(resp.content)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should've worked :

```
xfile = requests.get(candidate_link)
file_name = candidate_link.split('/')[-1]
if xfile:
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(xfile.content)
```

Tested with the following link I found randomly in google :

```
candidate_link = "http://berkeleycollege.edu/browser_check/samples/excel.xls"
```

Comment: thanks. the only modification I added as a concatenation to the folder path. seems to work just fine.